# Finding a plane numerically

Tags: co.combinatorics, oc.optimization-and-control, computational-geometry

Suppose I have three large finite sets $\{x_i\}$, $\{y_i\}$ and $\{z_i\}$;
they are obtained by measuring coordinates of a collection of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$, but I do not know which triples correspond to one vector.
Assume I know that all of the vectors lie in a plane, but I do not know which one.
I want to reconstruct this plane and the original collection of vectors.

Evidently the problem can be solved and the solution is unique if the original data is generic.
But I do not see a reasonable algorithm to solve this problem.
(For sure checking all subdivisions into triples is not a good idea.)

> Is there a numerical method to find this plane?

and

> Did anyone considered this or similar problem; does it have a name?

Comment: I wonder if a variant of the [Hough transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) would help? It is voting scheme, where the data votes for the most likely (in this case) plane that could explain the data.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke it seems to be closely related --- I have to think.

Comment: When you say "plane", do you mean a linear plane or an affine one?

Comment: @fedja you may think that it is a linear plane (you may also think that the average of coordinates vanishes).

Comment: @AntonPetrunin Yes, I understand the reduction of the generic affine scenario to the mean zero linear scenario. I just wondered whether we have a 2D problem or a 1D problem in the generic case. I also wonder how large the number $N$ of points is and whether the data is precise or noisy. The obvious algorithm would have running time above $N^5$ and noise tolerance below $N^{-2}$. The noise tolerance certainly decreases to $0$ in a power way as $N\to\infty$ (just think of how well you can match completely random data drawn from the uniform distribution, say), but these powers may be too high..

Comment: @fedja, yes there is noise, but I wanted keep things as simple as possible. In the case of uniform distribution one may think that the plane is not defined uniquely --- in this case it is okey to say "sorry I can not do it".

Comment: And how large is $N$?

Comment: If this can be of some help, what I hear of your problem is "I have three samples of correlated random variables and I'd like to know their correlation", so a primal instinct is to compute the variance of each set of coordinates. If the problem was about an affine line in $\mathbb R^2$, that would do it, but it does not seem to work in your case. In your case, the variance of the coordinates are somehow dependent, and restrict the possible planes, but it is less clear what to extract from this information.

Comment: Maybe Lattice reduction (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_reduction)  can be useful

Comment: @fedja If algorithm works for very large $N$, then I am very happy, but I am interested in any interested in any idea for such algorithm. A better approximation for the problem is a linear 2-plane  in $\mathbb{R}^q$ where $q=q(N)$ can grow in $N$, but not too fast, (maybe $q=\log N$).  (Maybe it will be sufficient to fight with noise.)

Comment: @AntonPetrunin  *If algorithm works for very large N*. That's exactly the problem. What I had in mind (some modification of Hough approach) is too expensive timewise ($N^5$ is way too much even for $N=10^3$) and the higher $N$ is, the harder the problem gets. But let me think :-)

Comment: What if the plane is $z=ax+by$ with $|a|,|b|$ both very very close to $1.$ Suppose the points $(x_i,y_i)$ are chosen randomly but approximately uniformly over the unit circle. It seems it would be pretty hard to decide the signs of $a$ and $b.$ The $z$ values would range from about $-\sqrt{2}$ to $\sqrt{2}.$

Comment: @AaronMeyerowitz that is right, in this case it  should say "sorry I can not do it".

Answer (score 2):

Here is a reasonable heuristic which you might turn into an algorithm. The idea is to look at generic possibilities inside the bounding box which covers the range of points. We start with imagining the product of three intervals. The first interval is [min x, max x], and we have similar for y and z.

Suppose we end up with a flat box (the z interval is relatively small). Then we know the normal to the plane is close to the z axis, and we can use that information to test various triples and rule out others.

For example, we can try a hexagon test, for example assume the normal is like (-c,-c,1). Then large values of x and y do not belong in the same tuple, as do small values. One can try (x,y,max z) as a test point for x+y close to Max x + mean y or mean y + max x.

Or we can try a ski slope test, where the normal is close to (0,-c,1), in which case x and z are not highly correlated but y correlates with z strongly. The point is that testing for such correlations is done pretty quickly, and can confirm or rule out a ski slope case.

In short, the plane is likely to resemble one case (two of the three sets are highly correlated), or the other (can't see the correlation, so can't have say all three coordinates be Max without saying something strong about the plane) which has implications for what pairs of numbers are allowed in a triple.

Gerhard  "Pretends There Aren't Many Planes" Paseman, 2019.05.20.

Answer (score 1):

defining as the initial set of grid points $\lbrace (x_i,y_j,z_k)\rbrace$, where the indices resemble initally given point numbers,
I would suggest to do the following:

repeatedly

- calculate the (geometric) least-squares plane through the remaining grid points
- remove a certain fraction of the remaining grid points, that are farthest away from the calculated plane

until all points are on the calculated plane.